# Put pager.html inside result.phtml instead of toolbar.phtml

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9.1

I'm trying to put a pagination on my **result.phtml** file using **pager.phtml** file creating a custom block:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'bottom.pager')->toHtml();
```

But i get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object
```

On Magento's default structure, the function **$this->getPagerHtml()** is used inside the file **toolbar.phtml**:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml
```

This function shows the default page navigation and the **toolbar.phtml** file is called on:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

by the function **$this->getToolbarHtml()** and the **list.phtml** file is called on:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalogsearch/result.phtml
```

by the function **$this->getProductListHtml()**.

How can i use the function **$this->getPagerHtml()** (or, somehow, use pagination) for paginate my results directly inside **result.phtml** without need of all these dependencies?

Comment: You'll probably need to add more info in order to get a good answer. For example, show the code that throws the error (where `getSize()` is used). Right now we're flying blind.

Comment: Thanks for hint! I edited the question, trying to help to understand better my issue.
At the beginning of **pager.phtml** file have this code
`<?php if ($this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>` and it's where i get the error.

Comment: That's definitely better. Sorry I don't know Magento at all to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Uou can use this code to add `pager` to your `result.phtml`. You must provide the collection using the `setCollection` function.

`_getProductCollection()` is a protected function from the class `Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result`, and gets current product collection.

```
<?php 
    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
    $pager = $layout->createBlock('page/html_pager');
    $pager->setCollection($this->_getProductCollection());
    echo $pager->toHtml();
 ?>
```